# How to securely store sensitive data on a shared-hosting provider while accessible to server-side scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, encryption

I want to store some sensitive data on my hosting provider which is a shared-hosting, lets say for example on MySQL, and i want it to be accessible to the website(server-side languages like PHP) hosted on same provider, how do i do that?

you see i can't use digest algorithms(MD5, SHA1, etc) beacause i want to restore data back to use them in code,

and

I can't use something like Public-Private Key because i have to store both keys on server, so it would be shared with hosting provider.

any ideas?

Comment: would only be accessible by the host staff, not other users of the same host

Comment: @Dagon That's in the best case. I've seen a hosting provider which didn't secure enough the directories so that I could with a php script browse all the other shared-hosts and download a file. After that, it's just a matter of searching for "config.php" to pown the DB

Comment: i have never seen such a host, i would say they are rare, as they would not last long.

Comment: @Dagon, you seem to assume that the random staff of a random service provider is trustworthy.. I think, in a IT security pessimistic view on life, you'd be better of assuming the exact opposite.

Comment: trust no one, live in a cave forage for food. its not possible to live with out some trust.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what you do I think you have to trust the hosting provider in this instance. You can't hide the information since, as you say your self, you must store the secret key ,unencrypted, on their server(s).

This is the reason for never storing sensitive data on someone else equipment if you don't trust them completely (and you should never do that). Just the fact that you consider doing this makes me think the data ain't really that sensitive at all (and in that case the entire discussion is pointless).

TL;DR
Don't share your secrets with other people, try to host your own sensitive data instead, if it really is that sensitive.